# Magento Store Switcher display one store instead of all

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, multi-website, store-switcher

I've create multiple website like below:

[image]

And in frontEnd i've displaying Store Switcher in the footer but my problem is not displaying all the stores defined above it will display only main website.

[image]

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated correctly, you have multiple **websites** - yet you are referring to the **store**-switcher in frontend.

So, you will have to implement a **website**-switcher in your template.
Examples are given in the references linked below:

```
<!-- BEGIN website switcher -->
<select id="website-changer" onChange="document.location=this.options[selectedIndex].value">
< ?php
$websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection();
foreach($websites as $website)
{
    $default_store = $website->getDefaultStore();
    $url_obj = new Mage_Core_Model_Url();
    $default_store_path = $url_obj->getBaseUrl(array('_store'=> $default_store->getCode()));
?>
    <option <?php if(strstr($this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(), $default_store_path)):?>selected="selected"< ?php endif; ?> value="< ?php echo $default_store_path ?>">< ?php echo $website->getName()?></option>
< ?php
}
?>
</select>
<!-- END website switcher -->
```

Some references on your question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270490/how-do-i-get-a-website-switcher-instead-of-store-switcher
- http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-snippet-for-switching-between-websites/